# GUI wallet stopped syncing

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I opened the gui wallet after a month of not using it.
It started syncing for a day but then just stopped.
It says it is connected and syncing but stays at the same last block.
I have restarted it several times but it stays the same.
I'm not sure what to do.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!
Don

Comment: Which specific block are you stuck at? It might be that you are using an outdated version. Are you using GUI beta 2?

Comment: I'm stuck at block 1288639. I'm using the first version.

Comment: I tried to download the latest version but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Do I extract the files that come up? What extraction path? Sorry I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Comment: Which OS are you using? You can download the latest version from here:

https://getmonero.org/downloads/

Extraction path can simply be a directory of your liking, as long as it does *not* contain spaces.

Comment: Try adding `--block-sync-size 20` to the daemon command line.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the new version. It was syncing and then the pc froze.

Comment: I restarted and now it wont sync again. I tried to start the monerod-exe,it starts up and then I get the message that there was a problem with the program and will shut down. Im using windows 8.1 Should I delete the wallet and reinstall? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I didn't get any notification from your comments. If your sync is stuck or monerod isn't working, please try this guide:

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it

Answer (score 3):

I'm very new at this, but I think that particular block was the fork.  This means you have to be running the newest Monero software, and the first version will not sync past that point.  (I'm having a similar problem, with a different block.)

Comment: You are correct. This is a couple dozen blocks after the fork, so this is a leftover chain maintained by a few miners which didn't update. Syncing the chain to the latest block requires monero 0.11.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Monero Gui (0.11.0.0 currently at this time).  Sometimes it will show Synchronizing and sometimes Connected: but don't worry, it's just finding some blocks on the available networks.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the update but the same thing happens.

Comment: It disconnects after a minute.

Comment: Height: 1332454/1332454 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 83.43 MH/s, v5, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 1s

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Comment: @DonCromarty Can you send me your daemon log ( It's in the monero gui application folder > file name: monero-wallet-gui.log ) < and the bitmonero log located @ ( C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\bitmonero.log or D:\ProgramData\bitmonero\bitmonero.log ).  **ARCHIVE** it, name it **ThisIsFileAxB2Q** and **PUT** the _password_ **GammaTangoFoxtrotWunTousandAitZeero** and **SEND** it to the facebook = [link](https://www.facebook.com/whiteisnotblack) .

Comment: @DonCromarty Or, you can try the instructions posted in this [link](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) and If this still does not work , then do what is stated above. Thank you! Sorry for the late response.

Comment: My Questions to you: Is your drive full or almost full? Is your internet laggy or slow?

Comment: Tip: Check if you have at least 10GB of storage left in your main drive.

Comment: Other questions: Did you stop your Gui wallet properly? Did you experience power interruption while running the Gui?

Comment: Try this Sir: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues/890

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sir: github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues/890

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.